# How to Add Full HTML, CSS, and JS in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So, i develop web app using Angular 7, one of the component however is using complex styling from old project, so i plan to just paste static HTML, CSS, and JS from static old project to one of the Angular component, how to do it?

i.e, I want to paste following HTML structure in Angular component:

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheets"..
   <link rel="stylesheets"..
   <link rel="stylesheets"..
</head>
<body>
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <script src="...
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that i need to use CSS and Script on that static page and only contained in single Angular component, i'm aware of declaring global CSS and JS that we need for our project in `angular.json`, however in this case i dont need global CSS or global JS, only contained on that one component, **so**, how to do it?

Comment: `@Component({
    selector: 'my-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['map.component.css', 'yourCustomStyle1.scss',........]})`

Comment: for the scripts it depends on what they do. IE: you shouldn't use JS/jQuery/etc to modify angular's html since it use it's own. So it's kinda hard to give you a quite good answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want certain styles contained in a single Angular component then you can define then with inline styles on your template.

1) Wrap styles with `style` tag:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <style>
    h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    <h1>This is a title.</h1>
    `
})
```

2) Normal inline styles in the template tags:

```
@Component({
  template: '<h1 style="color:blue">This is a title.</h1>'
})
```

You can also include the script tags in your template to import a JS file whenever you're using this component.

3) Alternatively you can import the CSS files by using `@import` in your CSS file for the component:

```
@Component({
  template: '<h1>This is a title.</h1>',
  style: '@import url("custom.css");'
})
```

Comment: it's not possible, there are more than 15 CSS files and JS to be included for just that one single HTML file

Comment: if you put the styles like that they will affect every child component of the used component. Just put it in the component's css file so Angular can give them a selector.

Comment: @SebOlens what do you mean?

Comment: @.xcode if you have that many files then why not using the @import on the css file for your component?

Comment: how about JS inside <script> tag? the JS files mostly from third party libraries like jquery etc.

Comment: @.xcode yes, you can use `<script>` tags in the html template to import 3rd party JS files